# NodeJS Sendgrid 401 unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

After registering a user in my node express server, I would like to send a verification email. If the user is created I use this function to send the email:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

const sendEmail = (to, token) => {
    const msg = {
        to,
        from: process.env.SENDGRID_SENDER,
        subject: 'Email Verification',
        text: `Please click the following link: http://localhost:5000/${token}`
    }
    
    sgMail
     .send(msg)
     .then((response) => {
        console.log(response[0].statusCode)
        console.log(response[0].headers)
    })
     .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
    })
}

export { sendEmail }
```

It is called here:

```
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body

  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('User already exists')
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password
  })

  if (user) {
    sendEmail(user.email, user.token) //HERE
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      isVerified: user.isVerified,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    })
  } else {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('Invalid user data')
  }
})
```

The problem I am having is I get a ResponseError Unauthorized (code 401) when the request is made. The user does get created in the system. On my sendgrid account, I have verified the sender email with full access and I am storing my API Key in my .env file.

I have used 10 minute mail accounts to test this and real email accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 401 status is coming from **sendgrid** then probably your env variable is not resolved.
try this line after you import the `dotenv` package

```
dotenv.config()
```

If it didn't work, try to console.log the `process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY` before u use it to make sure it's there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  It was misleading because their SENDGRID_API_KEY matches up with the nomenclature of the smaller string.  I figured the longer one was the secret.  Use the longer string for the key.  That one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail' and set your api key sgMail.setApiKey('your api key is here')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please improvise your answer with code comments

Comment: That worked for me, I needed to pass the apikey